# Is this a valid qualitative description of objects moving under gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Context: I am a physics teacher trying to write an introductory astronomy course for an educational website. I studied some cosmology at university, but not general relativity. I want to see if the model of gravity I have in my head is valid, and my research so far has neither confirmed nor contradicted it.

My description:
"Objects in orbit don't move in a curved line due to a force, they move in a straight line through curved space-time. **The reason a stationary object can appear to accelerate is that it is space-time that is curved by mass, not just space. Even stationary objects move through time, so when they are in curved space-time their motion through time can start to translate into motion through space, in much the same way that motion in the x-direction can be translated into motion in the y direction by a curve in space.**

I just want to know if the stuff in bold is true. If it is I can think about how to explain it better, but if it isn't this would be a poor use of my time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is basically correct.

The motion of a freely falling object is described by the geodesic equation. Suppose we choose some coordinate system $(t, x, y, z)$ then in our coordinates we write the acceleration of the falling object as:

$$ \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2} = - \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta $$

where we are using index notation $x^0 = t$, $x^1 = x$, $x^2 = y$ and $x^3 = z$ so this is a shorthand for writing the four equations:

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{d^2 t}{d\tau^2} &= - \Gamma^t_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta \\
 \frac{d^2 x}{d\tau^2} &= - \Gamma^x_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta \\
 \frac{d^2 y}{d\tau^2} &= - \Gamma^y_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta \\
 \frac{d^2 z}{d\tau^2} &= - \Gamma^z_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta
\end{align}$$

And we use the Einstein summation convention:

$$ \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta = \sum_{\alpha = 0}^3 \sum_{\beta=0}^3 \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta $$

so each of our four equations above contains 16 terms on the right hand side (though in practice many of the terms will be zero).

The *acceleration* $d^2x^\mu/d\tau^2$ is the four acceleration i.e. the second derivative of position with respect to the proper time of the falling object not the coordinate time measured on our clocks. The symbols $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ are the Christoffel symbols that describe how the spacetime is curved, and $u$ is the four velocity of the object.

This all looks a bit fearsome, but if we consider a stationary object (stationary in our chosen coordinates that is) then the four velocity is:

$$ \mathbf u = (u^t, 0, 0, 0) $$

that is only the time component of the four velocity is non-zero. So going back to the equations above we find that of all the possible $u^\alpha u^\beta$ terms only $u^t u^t$ is non-zero and the equations simplify dramatically to expressions like:

$$  \frac{d^2 x}{d\tau^2} = - \Gamma^x_{tt} u^t u^t $$

So going back to your question it is true that the acceleration in e.g. the $x$ direction is non-zero because the object is moving through time at some non-zero four velocity $u^t$. The acceleration is also proportional to $\Gamma^x_{tt}$ i.e. how curved the spacetime is.

Comment: It would classically be the force, and in GR the interpretation is harder to explain. - mainly when we know we can make all the gammas zero at one point of our choosing at any one time. So it does not represent curvature, it's not invariant geometrical object (no tensor). Shouldn't the answer to the OP be that their words interpreting are very very loosely tied to the real meanings? I don't mean to discourage someone, and I know you're trying to make it as close to reality as possible, but shouldn't they know that it's too conceptually loose, and recommend a little more preciseness?

Comment: :this should precede the comment above, I misspelled things.  I appreciate help to those starting out, but the interpretation of equations, IMO, is not really elucidating, it excuses a verbal explanation which is not too clear either. $u^t$ is not moving through time, it is how coordinate time changes (not moves) in terms of proper time, i.e. some time dilation factor. I know you know all this so it's really the implications that it is asome explanation that I object to. Slightly. The gammas as you know are the gradients in some combined ways, of the potential (phi), so ----> to previous